# APPS Script Function Not allowing others to run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a script that updates a google form via google sheets. I need this to be administered by other staff.

There are multiple functions but they all are identical to the screenshot below, just editing different parts of the form.

Is anyone able to give me some advice so other staff can use these functions too?

PS. I have the functions tied to a "button" (image) on the google sheet.

[image: Apps Script Function Example]

Comment: From your showing script, it seems that your script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. In that case, how about sharing the Spreadsheet with the specific users you want to use? By this, the users except for the specific users cannot be accessed. But, I'm not sure about your actual environment. For example, when you are using Google Workspace and when all users have the viewer or writer permission as the default, it is required to think of another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to run a function by clicking a button (image) from a script contained by a spreadsheet, the users should be spreadsheet editors.

In order to be able to modify a form, users should be form editors.

Conclusion

Share the spreadsheet and the form as editors with the users that have to run a bounded script to edit the respective form.